# Excel User Form Files Drag & Drop

Tags: excel, drag-and-drop, userform, vba

I'd like to implement a Drag&Drop object on a User Form in Excel 2016.
The purpose is to allow Drag&Drop of files (from Windows Files Explorer) onto the Excel User Form, and catch the drop event to extract file(s) path and names.

So far, I found it is achievable with a very old control that is not provided in recent years anymore by Microsoft - the Treeview control. This control works perfect for my need, however, requires a special registration on of an old OCX and a TLB file that are not common on standard users' run-time machines, not are common (and working) their registration tools, such as Regtlibv12 / Regtlib on new Windows 10 with Office 2016 64bit.

I wonder - is it possible that Microsoft offers no controls to to this in recent years? Do you know if this is achievable with standard Windows 10 and Office 2016 64bit offerings?

Comment: Does something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/filedialog-object-office) help you?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Drag & Drop. This is a standard File Dialog call.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by hooking the userform, and using the Windows API
I adapted some code from [Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/408038-drag-drop-file-visual-basic-applications.html)

Note this copyright:

> ' This code was originally written by Dev Ashish. 
>   ' It is not to be altered or distributed, 
>   ' except as part of an application. 
>   ' You are free to use it in any application, 
>   ' provided the copyright notice is left unchanged. 
>   ' 
>   ' Code Courtesy of ' Dev Ashish

(Although I've adapted some of it) In the userform, put this code:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal 
lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Function hWnd() As Long
Dim hWndThis As Long
If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then
    hWndThis = FindWindow(lpClassName:="ThunderDFrame", lpWindowName:=Me.Caption)
Else
    hWndThis = FindWindow(lpClassName:="ThunderXFrame", lpWindowName:=Me.Caption)
End If
hWnd = hWndThis
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call sEnableDrop(Me, hWnd)
Call sHook(hWnd)
End Sub

Private Declare Function apiCallWindowProc Lib "user32" _
Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, _
ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal Msg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByVal lParam As Long) _
As Long

Private Declare Function apiSetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal wNewWord As Long) _
As Long

Private Declare Function apiGetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) _
As Long

Private Declare Sub sapiDragAcceptFiles Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "DragAcceptFiles" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal fAccept As Long)

Private Declare Sub sapiDragFinish Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "DragFinish" _
(ByVal hDrop As Long)

Private Declare Function apiDragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "DragQueryFileA" _
(ByVal hDrop As Long, _
ByVal iFile As Long, _
ByVal lpszFile As String, _
ByVal cch As Long) _
As Long

Private lpPrevWndProc  As Long
Private Const GWL_WNDPROC  As Long = (-4)
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20)
Private Const WM_DROPFILES = &H233
Private Const WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES = &H10&
Private hWnd_Frm As Long

Sub sDragDrop(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                        ByVal Msg As Long, _
                        ByVal wParam As Long, _
                        ByVal lParam As Long)

Dim lngRet As Long, strTmp As String, intLen As Integer
Dim lngCount As Long, i As Long, strOut As String
Const cMAX_SIZE = 50
On Error Resume Next
If Msg = WM_DROPFILES Then
    strTmp = String$(255, 0)
    lngCount = apiDragQueryFile(wParam, &HFFFFFFFF, strTmp, Len(strTmp))
    For i = 0 To lngCount - 1
        strTmp = String$(cMAX_SIZE, 0)
        intLen = apiDragQueryFile(wParam, i, strTmp, cMAX_SIZE)
        strOut = strOut & Left$(strTmp, intLen) & ";"
    Next i
    strOut = Left$(strOut, Len(strOut) - 1)
    Call sapiDragFinish(wParam)
    MsgBox strOut

Else
    lngRet = apiCallWindowProc( _
                        ByVal lpPrevWndProc, _
                        ByVal hWnd, _
                        ByVal Msg, _
                        ByVal wParam, _
                        ByVal lParam)
End If
End Sub

Sub sEnableDrop(frm As UserForm, hWnd As Long)
Dim lngStyle As Long, lngRet As Long
lngStyle = apiGetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
lngStyle = lngStyle Or WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES
lngRet = apiSetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lngStyle)
Call sapiDragAcceptFiles(hWnd, True)
hWnd_Frm = hWnd
End Sub


Sub sHook(hWnd As Long)
lpPrevWndProc = apiSetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf sDragDrop)
End Sub

Sub sUnhook(hWnd As Long)
Dim lngTmp As Long
lngTmp = apiSetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, lpPrevWndProc)
lpPrevWndProc = 0
End Sub
```

The sDragDrop function puts the file list to a messagebox, but you can set a variable to store it.

OF course, as it is hooking the window, then it is a risk to stability!

Comment: Thanks @ainwood! Good to know there's a way, however awkward that goes through hooking the Window, and no trivial control within Excel that just supports the Drop event. One would think it is an acceptable expectation nowadays... Another thing, it makes the whole form droppable. I want a certain area that I can also format (as in "drop files here" text with visible frame and fill color).

Comment: Theoretically..... You should be able to add a control onto the form (eg. a Frame(, use `GetWindow(hWndParent, GW_CHILD)` to find the window of that control, and hook that.  However, the problem is that if you have more than one control on the form, you need to know which control is which.  Unfortunately, there are two problems:  WIndows Form Controls don't have different class names or window text to distinguish them, so you'd have to have some dodgy "fudge" on its the (say) 4th hWnd in the list.  Secondly, the messages get passed-through to the Userform anyway, even if hooking the child.

Comment: Of course, you could just create a "Drop Files Here" frame, and rely on the fact that the drop will still get passed through to the form, even if the user "misses" dropping in the right area.  Or you could have a frame with a MouseMove that sets an "Allow Drop" boolean if the mouse is over that frame, and have the drop code exiting if the boolean is not set.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, but I always like simple, elegant solutions, and this is going too far for achieving what should be a standard event nowadays. I prefer to stay with a solid application, and allow uploading files only through the File Dialog using an upload button.